# Apply for two positions under the same supervisor

Tags: applications

There are two positions that interest me under exactly the same supervisor. I have already contacted him through telephone and he told me that my qualifications make me a better candidate for the "lower" one. However, I **must** apply for the one with the most requirements because it was proposed to me by the job center (living in Germany, I may lose my unemployment benefits if I do not comply). The deadline is the same for both positions.

Is it ok to apply for both positions, given that my applications will reach the same person at the same time? Clearly I will try to personalize them for each position and also indicate (by including a serial number) that I was forced to apply for the higher one. But still, does it sound desperate?

Comment: Did you call the job center about it?

Answer (score 3):

Apply for each position. Attach a note to each application where you explain that while [state the supervisor's name] stated that you are a better candidate for the [state the name of the lower position] and you accept that, [state the name of the job center] requires that you apply for [state the name of the higher position] on pain of losing your benefits. Hence, the fact that you are applying for both positions.

You do what you have to do. You are desperate if you choose to be desperate. Even when situations are bad, we still get to choose how we react to them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How about if I only apply for the senior position and include a note in my email saying that I would like to be considered for the lower position as well?

Comment: Don't be lazy. It's not worth it to take chances. If the supervisor takes a look at your application for the senior position and decides to dump it, the supervisor still has your fully filled-in application for the junior position to work with.

Comment: It is not a matter of laziness, I just thought it would seem a bit desperate, as if I am trying to get any job possible. Plus, the two roles have similar duties (oddly enough), so my cover letter would be pretty much the same...

Comment: @Flatron1917 It's not about you being desperate, it's about you being qualified for the positions you are applying for. You are qualified, therefore you apply. In the case of where you are being made to apply, the desperation if any comes comes from complying to keep your benefits, it's not desperation for a job per se. You do what you have to do. Once you're through with having made the choice to do what you have to do, put the experience behind you, be at peace with yourself and give both positions your level best :)